# Firebase returns "null" account after successful authentication

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Why does Firebase return "null" account after successful Google Play authentication?

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        [...]

        val activity = this
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode("<some-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .build()
        val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso)
        val acc = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity) // This is null
        val currentUser = Firebase.auth.currentUser // This is null

        signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val account = task.result // This is com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount@123456

                account.displayName // This is null
                account.id // This is null
                Firebase.auth.currentUser // Still null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the docs user id should never be "null" if "isSuccessful" was triggered: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games

Comment: If you want to sign in with Google and use that with Firebase Auth, you shouldn't use the Google Signin API to perform the actual sign in process, because Firebase will not know about the result of it, and the current user from Firebase's perspective will always be null.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) for examples.  If you aren't trying to use Firebase at all and just Google Signin, then please remove Firebase from the code and description here because it's not relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I want to use free/automatic authentication of Google Play and create a Firestore entry /users/user_id. The official Google documentation says to do it using GoogleSignIn. It seems the "account" is returning everything "null" despite successful sign in, but the returned "serverAuthCode" can be converted to Firebase "credential". Nonetheless, the entire process is so far very messy and confusing when there are 2 independent sign-in methods that aren't compatible in any simple way.

Comment: Honestly, it just doesn't look like you're following the instructions in the documentation you linked. At some point you need to call Firebase's `auth.signInWithCredential(credential)` to let Firebase know about the signed in user, and I don't see that at all here.

Comment: I'm following precisely https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games - it says to do silent sign-in with Google Play and then convert `serverAuthCode` to "credential" and have userId for Firebase this way. But they use `acct.id!!` which is wrong because it results in `NullPointerException` and other things are also `null`. But I think I may be getting closer because I just realized `serverAuthCode` is defined, so maybe that's all I needed.

Comment: IT WORKS! Using `PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential` instead of `GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential` makes it compatible with Google Play silent sign-in. But it seems this will not qualify for the "free" tier (default Google Play sign-in is free), so it may not be that attractive for most users? I will answer this question later when I will successfully configure everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can only implement authentication with Google but if you want to also use Firebase products, then you should also authenticate in Firebase too. This means that you should follow these steps. First, sign in with Google. Once the authentication is successful, get the Google credentials and pass them to the [FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) method. Please check below the documentation for [One Tap sign-in and sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started). And here is the documentation for implementing [Firebase sign-in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

Here is also a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) that might help, with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

While the above solution will definitely work, please note that the One Tap sign-in will be soon deprecated. So you should consider [Integrate Credential Manager with Sign in with Google](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-manager).

Comment: Thanks! I think it's solved for me. What confused me is that the docs page I linked to contains `acct.id!!`, implying that this has to be set to some value if `isSuccessful` was `true`. But for me it's `null`, so I thought I was doing something wrong (especially, since the default `PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(activity).isAuthenticated` returns display name etc. by default and for `GoogleSignIn.getClient()` it doesn't). But `serverAuthCode` is set using this replacement sign-in method (`GoogleSignIn.getClient()`), so it's fine. Too bad double sign-in is required for 1 user but OK.

Comment: The Firebase sign-in is required so you can secure the Firebase products, like Firestore, Realtime Database, or Cloud Storage for Firebase.

Comment: And you're very welcome, Jimsea.

Comment: Hey Jimsea. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes, it did help, thank you very much, I upvoted it already yesterday and now I accepted it as a solution.